# Eating 2 meals Erev Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur

There are those that eat two Seudos on Erev Yom kippur and those that eat only one. What is the source of eating either 2 or 1?

Comment: Besides for eating two meals, there is a mitzvah to eat on Erev Yom Kippur. It is brought down in Seforim that if someone eats on Erev Yom Kippur, it is like he fasted on the 9th of Tishrei and the 10th. Then when we fast on Yom Kippur, it is like we fasted three days in a row!

Comment: @da that would be 2 days...

Answer (score 7):

From [Rabbi Yissachar Dov Krakowski](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/article.php?p=70599):

> One must eat at least the seudas
>   Hamafsekes.
>
> 1. There is a largely accepted minhag to eat two seudos Erev
>      Yom-Kippur: one in the morning and one
>      in the afternoon.
> 2. One should eat meat for the Seudas Hamafsekes.
>           There are those that eat Dairy for the morning meal, but many
>      are noheg to eat meat for both.

Answer (score 0):

No one discusses a minhag to HAVE a morning meal in addition to the Seudah Hamafsekes. The discussion is having meat at your pre-existing morning meal. The assumption is that you ALWAYS have a morning meal. Some call this "breakfast." The assumption is that you sit for this meal and have bread always (Pas Boker). In the times of the Rishonim people didn't simply grab a coffee and a yogurt on the way to the train station.

Comment: CJ, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for posting this answer. You could make this answer stronger by [edit]ing in citations of representative sources for the discussion about having meat at breakfast and for the assumption of "Pas Boker." I hope you'll stick around, enjoy Mi Yodeya, and keep contributing. You might find our 150 other [tag:yom-kippur] questions a good place to continue. Gemar Chatima Tova!

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry but is a know an also published minhag to eat two meals.
Not a breakfast but just before mincha (starting before chatsot).

In the books I did read about this they write to eat fish in the first meal and meat in the erev Jom kipur meal.
I also I understood that the two meals are for the two Jom tov meal.
one says because erev Jom Kipur is like a Jom Tov and another says it are the Jom Tov meals for Jom Kipur.
I think they add up to the same.

I am not with mine sforim so I can not check the place so I will not bring it.
On the Internet I did found the following places.
The first two I know as reliable the 3th I was not able to post.

http://www.aish.com/h/hh/r/48954391.html
http://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/989587/jewish/Pre-Fast-Feasting.htm

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Jan! Thanks for the answer! Consider adding some primary sources, it is fine if these are culled from the linked websites.