# Eating Ginger instead of Garlic in Shabbat Evening

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, leil-shabbat

There is a practice to eat garlic on Shabbat Evening, as mentioned in the Gemara (Baba Kama 82:1) :  `בגמ' בב"ק (פב.): "עשרה תקנות תיקן עזרא... ואוכלין שום בערב שבת`"

One of the reasons that stands beyond this custom is that it helps males in Periya Ureviya. Can men replace the garlic with ginger that has the same effects and its eater has a good smell from his mouth after eating it? In addition, is the minhag applicable only to a married man?

Comment: How do you know ginger has the same effect?

Comment: See this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45897/603 -- there is a list of foods that are forbidden to eat on erev yom kippur because they increase zerah. Ginger is not on that list. If the only reason for the takanah was to  increase zerah, perhaps you'd be able to exchange it with something else that does the same think. Your question seems to indicate that there are other reasons given. Depending on those reasons, it may or may not be permissible to exchange the garlic with something else.